# SSIS Lookup transformation to insert data in table

Tags: ssis

I have created a lookup transformation to search 2 table col for matching data and then insert another column data from matching data into the other table. My problem is how can i insert the matching data into that tabl[image]e i have shown in the shot.

Comment: Could you not use an OLEDB destination to do the insert? If you want to update the column then you can use an OLEDB Update command.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to insert the lookup matched cols by inserting OLEDB Command and Writing update query

Update dbo.city set fdocode = ? where id = ?

and then Map the col i want to insert to first parameter and id to second parameter.see shot for more clarity.

[image]